# Prevent assignment in conditional expression in visual studio 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, fxcop, stylecop

Given the following code:

```
    bool test = false;
    bool test2 = true;

    if (test = test2)
    {

    }
```

I want to get a warning when compiling this code as probably I wanted == instead.
I don't get a warning from compiler and can't find a code analysis rule anywhere for it (fxcop or stylecop).

The closest compiler warning I found was CS0665:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c1sde1ax%28v=vs.90%29.aspx
But this only triggers if I do:

```
if (test = true)
```

- Can anybody point me to an existing rule or tool I can integrate into my build process that will trigger on this?
- Is there a good reason why we would want to allow this first construct?

Comment: FWIW, its not really VS that is allowing this as an assignment, but .NET.  Also, ReSharper catches this, but does not throw a warning by default.  It could be configured to do so however.

Comment: If you have this problem a lot, then you've got bigger problems as well. You'd do well to address all the similar problems (low-experience developers, insufficient code review and insufficient QA).

Comment: A reason you _could_ want to use this sort of construct is something like `string bar; if (foo == null || (bar = GetABar()) == null) return;`. This keeps you from either eagerly evaluating GetABar() or adding an assignment line and another if.

Answer (score 3):

ReSharper will display a warning for this, saying:

```
Expression is always true
```

I would suggest using 'Configure inspection severity' and upgrading it to an `Error`

Comment: @DieterDHoker do you use ReSharper?